# Can you upgrade more than one class at once with the Visual Studio .NET Upgrade Assistant

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm trying to use the Visual Studio Upgrade Assistant to help me upgrade a .NET Framework Webforms app to .NET 8. I have hundreds of C# classes it can automatically transfer over using this interface, but it doesn't let me choose more than one at a time.

Is there some way to automatically upgrade more than one class without using the CLI?

[image]

Comment: Very little code changes will be required to some classes you used. Where holly hellfire and everything going to break down? The migration assistant does not, will not, and CAN NOT upgrade web forms to .net core for you. All it can do is place a web site in FRONT of the webforms, and hand off the url to that EXISTING web form. Again: the upgrade assistant does not ,can not, and WILL not upgrade webforms to .net core applications. So, the only benefit here is upgrading a single class that is NOT part of a web form. And 99% of such classes will upgrade without code changes anyway.

Comment: So upgrading some classes is easy, and as noted, in most cases such .net classes don't need much of any changes to those .net classes. However, an existing web form and it's code behind? That is a MASSIVE and Mount Everest of a differrent issue, and those existing web forms (and the code behind class for that web form) can NOT be upgraded by the upgrade assistant. Those pages will require a 100% re-writing and re-building of such pages into the MVC design pattern, or at the very least the blazer syntax for such web pages. That is a 100% hand and human labor conversion and is not automated.